# How do I deserialize this string to my POJO representation using Jackson in Java?

Tags: java, jackson

```
public class UpdateRequest {
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty
    private long version;
    @JsonProperty("fields")
    private Map<String, String> values;
}
```

My Input looks like this:

```
{ 
  "id":"1",
  "type":"add",
  "version": 20146780,
  "fields": {
  "pid":"1234",
  "location":"99,100",
  "lastModified":"2013-12-30T22:15:37.482Z"
  }
}
```

This is how I am currently doing it using Jackson but it fails. What am I missing here?

```
public Optional<UpdateRequest> deserialize(String message) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Optional<UpdateRequest> updateRequest = Optional
                .empty();
        try {
            updateRequest = Optional.of(mapper.readValue(message,
                    UpdateRequest.class));
            System.out.println(mapper
                    .writeValueAsString(updateRequest));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return updateRequest;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what Optional class does here, but you can get the UpdateRequest object by doing

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = mapper.readValue(message, UpdateRequest.class);
```

You might want to take a look on this document, [JacksonInFiveMinutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

Comment: I am getting an exception

Comment: Would you post first couple lines of the exception?